# Patch Value for nested fb.group and fb.array - Reactive Forms

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I have the following Reactive form:

```
this.cvForm = this._fb.group({
  sector: ['', [Validators.required]],
  background: ['', [Validators.required]],
  experience: this._fb.group({
    field0: ['', [Validators.required]],
    field1: ['', [Validators.required]],
    field2: ['', [Validators.required]],
    field3: ['', [Validators.required]],
    field4: [''],
    field5: ['']
  }),
  skills: this._fb.array([]),
  iconOne: ['', [Validators.required]],
  iconTwo: ['', [Validators.required]],
  iconThree: ['', [Validators.required]],
  iconFour: ['', [Validators.required]],
  otherSkills: ['', [Validators.required]]
});
}
```

I am retrieving the values to "patched" from the DB and using below to`patchValue`:

```
 onCVRetrieved(cv: ICV): void {
   if (this.cvForm) {
     this.cvForm.reset();
  }

  this.cv = cv; // this contains the values returned from the DB

  this.cvForm.patchValue({

  sector: this.cv.sector,
  background: this.cv.background,
  experience: this._fb.group({
    field0: ['', [Validators.required]],
    field1: ['', [Validators.required]],
    field2: ['', [Validators.required]],
    field3: ['', [Validators.required]],
    field4: [''],
    field5: ['']
  }),
  skills: this._fb.array([]),
  iconOne: this.cv.iconOne,
  iconTwo: this.cv.iconTwo,
  iconThree: this.cv.iconThree,
  iconFour:this.cv.iconFour

})

}
```

**The issue:**

I am struggling to `patchValue` for the **nested fb.group** and **fb.array**:

```
experience: this._fb.group({
    field0: ['', [Validators.required]],
    field1: ['', [Validators.required]],
    field2: ['', [Validators.required]],
    field3: ['', [Validators.required]],
    field4: [''],
    field5: ['']
  })

skills: this._fb.array([])
```

**Any idea how I can patchValue for the above 2 instances?**

**Update:**

The nested fb.group worked:

```
 this.cvForm.controls['experience'].patchValue({
  field0: this.cv.experience['field0'],
  field1: this.cv.experience['field1'],
  field2: this.cv.experience['field2'],
  field3: this.cv.experience['field3'],
  field4: this.cv.experience['field4'],
  field5: this.cv.experience['field5']
});
```

**Issue with fb.array:**

The structure of the array data from server is like this:

```
skills: ["something", "something else", "another thing", "one more thing"]
```

On the front end I have massive list of skills where are checkboxes. I want to auto check the values in front-end that have been returned from the DB. So for example: If the DB returns array of skills which includes **"singing"**. The singing should be checked on the front end.

**What I have tried:**

```
 const formArray = new FormArray([]);

 const skills: [String] = this.cv.skills;
 skills.forEach(item => formArray.push(new FormControl('')));

this.cvForm.patchValue({

  sector: this.cv.sector,
  background: this.cv.background,
  skills: formArray.patchValue(skills),
  iconOne: this.cv.iconOne,
  iconTwo: this.cv.iconTwo,
  iconThree: this.cv.iconThree,
  iconFour: this.cv.iconFour

});
```

**Front-end:**

**Please note that the list of all possible checkboxes is fetched from the DB.**

```
<div class="uk-margin">
    <div *ngFor="let skill of allSkills">
      <input type="checkbox"> {{skill}}<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`FormArray` has to have exactly as many controls as there are items in the array that is going to be set as its value. For example, if you have this array:

```
const arr = [1,2,3];
```

And this `FormArray`:

```
const formArray = new FormArray([]); // equivalent to fb.array([])\
```

You may want to do something like this:

```
arr.forEach(item => formArray.push(new FormControl('')));
```

And only then:

```
formArray.patchValue(arr);
```

As to `FormGroup`, it already has the necessary structure and can be easily patched:

```
const formGroup = fb.group({
    name: [''],
    lastName: ['']
});
formGroup.patchValue({
   name: 'Foo',
   lastName: 'Bar'
});
```

And about your code: it seems you do not patch a valid value in your code. Look, the object you pass to the `patchValue` method contains fields like

```
experience: this._fb.group({
field0: ['', [Validators.required]],
field1: ['', [Validators.required]],
field2: ['', [Validators.required]],
field3: ['', [Validators.required]],
field4: [''],
field5: ['']
  })
```

and

```
skills: this._fb.array([]),
```

Those are not the values you want to assign to the form, those are new declarations of a `FormGroup` and `FormArray`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try it now. One question. I have a `nested formGroup`. the `cvForm` group has a nested `experience` formGroup. How do I patch Values for that nested form group?

Comment: Just use an object with a nested object, just make sure the structure is the same.

Comment: Hi, The nested fb group worked. But not the fb array for some reason.

Comment: What did it look like? Did it throw an error? And what does the array you want to patch look like? Provide some insight and I'll be able to help you

Comment: hi, Ive updated my question with some detail. Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `skills: this._fb.array([]),` this looks like an empty form array, but you say you have lots of checkobxes. Can you please also add the part of your html where the checkoxes are declared?

Comment: Do you have a list of **all** possible checkboxes is your component?

Comment: Hi. I've updated my question for more detail. The list of all possible checkboxes is fetched from the DB. and then I fetch the the checkbox items that were "checked" by the user from their account within the DB and `patch` them to the form. Does this make sense?